# Are NetBSD provide digital signatures for official ISO images and binary packages?

Tags: security, package-management, netbsd, integrity

I just install NetBSD in from ISO image inside VirtualBox.

Official source ISO media [contains only MD5/SHA512 sums](ftp://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/NetBSD/NetBSD-7.0/images/).

Similarly [pkg_add binary packag repository](ftp://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/pkgsrc/packages/NetBSD/i386/7.0/) contains only SHA512 sums.

Both FTP and HTTP distribution channels is unsecured and check sums file transfer may be altered.

Is digital signature used by NetBSD project?

How enforce checks for package integrity when `pkg_add` is used?

Answer (score 4):

A [PGP-signed list of hashes](http://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/NetBSD/security/hashes/NetBSD-7.0_hashes.asc) is available, covering all the release files. The PGP key used to sign this is well connected in the web of trust.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Does `pkg_add` aware about PGP keys? Where is trusted store located on local machine? I set `PKG_PATH` env var but can't figure out how I should accept signing keys...

Comment: I can't find any signatures for NetBSD packages; there's a the [list of SHA-512 hashes](ftp://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/pkgsrc/packages/NetBSD/x86_64/7.0_2016Q1/SHA512.bz2) but it isn't signed.